# why am i getting an error while using either RandomSearchCV or GridSearchCV with logistic regression?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

`````
pipe=Pipeline(steps=[('standardscaler', StandardScaler()),
                 ('logisticregression', LogisticRegression())])
pipe.fit(X_train,y_train)
random_estimator = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = pipe,
                               param_distributions = random_grid,
                               n_iter = 100,
                               scoring = 'accuracy',
                               n_jobs = -1,
                               verbose = 1, 
                               random_state = 42,
                              )


random_estimator.fit(X,y)````
`````

i know i am making some noob error but after this i am getting an error

> ValueError: Invalid parameter warm_start for estimator
> Pipeline(steps=[('standardscaler', StandardScaler()),
> ('logisticregression', LogisticRegression())]). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.

after running pipe.get_params().keys() i am getting this

```
pipe.get_params().keys()
```

> dict_keys(['memory', 'steps', 'verbose', 'standardscaler',
> 'logisticregression', 'standardscaler__copy',
> 'standardscaler__with_mean', 'standardscaler__with_std',
> 'logisticregression__C', 'logisticregression__class_weight',
> 'logisticregression__dual', 'logisticregression__fit_intercept',
> 'logisticregression__intercept_scaling',
> 'logisticregression__l1_ratio', 'logisticregression__max_iter',
> 'logisticregression__multi_class', 'logisticregression__n_jobs',
> 'logisticregression__penalty', 'logisticregression__random_state',
> 'logisticregression__solver', 'logisticregression__tol',
> 'logisticregression__verbose', 'logisticregression__warm_start'])

can anyone explain the error thank you!!

Comment: For future questions, be sure to include the programming language and relevant library/package tags for a faster response. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `random_grid` parameters dictionary currently likely includes the `warm_start` parameter, something like:

```
random_grid = {'warm_start': [True, False]}
```

That name needs to match the `logisticregression__warm_start` name you see among the pipeline parameter keys in your question:

```
random_grid = {'logisticregression__warm_start': [True, False]}
```